# What's the name of a solid that results from extruding an area straight along an axis?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, definition

If you have any kind of 2D shape and move it up into the third dimension, what do you call it, because it seems like prism is used only if the base is a polygon.

It also seems like extrusion is a more general term and not strictly a mathematical one as shown in the link:

[wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Extrusi%C3%B3n-tipos_-I%C3%B1aki_Otsoa._CC._By_ShA_$no-.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In varying contexts, I've seen this type of object called a (*generalized*) *cylinder*; a *tube*; or a *prism*. If you're looking for a term to use in some piece of writing, the main things are to use something simple and familiar, and to be explicit about your meaning if the term is non-standard (or there's other danger of ambiguity).

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a [*cylinder*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html) — a *right cylinder* if the movement is normal to the plane of the original two-dimensional region. However, *cylinder* is used in enough different senses that I’d probably explain my usage first.

Comment: Yes,  that's what my math professor called it,  but don't you think it's still a bit too ambiguous because the word is also used to describe a shape where the base is a circle?

Comment: @good_one: It’s a standard usage, and I’ve no problem with it. The potential ambiguity is why I said that I’d probably explain it the first time I used it in a given context.